# Angular ngx-translate to retrieve json file content

Tags: json, angular, database, browser, ngx-translate

Instead of storing the contents of a translation JSON file into an HTTP loader, I am looking to store the JSON contents into browser's local database.

Is there any way I can extend loader to read and print out JSON file contents from `TranslateHttpLoader`?

File path: `/folder/i18n/en.json`

Contents inside en.json

```
{
  "name" : "andrew",
  "email" : "andrew@aol.com"
}
```

Then on the HTML page, set it into the browser database

```
key = "en";
value = content from en.json
value = translate.getTranslation('en');

localStorage.setItem("en", value);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Your question doesn't give full details. Please provide a question with full details and what are you expecting from it?

Comment: just edited the post

Comment: So what I understand is you want to save your json data into local storage? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, so that every time translate is loading json data from browser local storage, not from the json file url .

Comment: That is not a recommended step, it should be loaded from json file. As when we load our page, its assets folder is already loaded, so why do you need to add it in local storage?